# Removing Taskbar Jumplist?

Tags: c#, jump-list, windows-api-code-pack

So I was messing about with JumpLists from the Windows API Code Pack for Microsoft .NET, and there is a slight problem that seems to have occurred.
After removing or editing the code, references and deleting the libraries themselves, the jumplist still remains.[image: JumpList Code]

What I would like to know is, how can I remove this JumpList from my program? (The image shows edited code, and the result, which was the previously present code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory that stores jumplists can be found by going to

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\
```

In this path you can select and delete the jumplists you no longer want...

Comment: Deleted both the most recently accessed files (the time is roundabout when I first added the JumpList), and it is still on the program.

Comment: @LiamMcSherry Also, have you tried right-clicking on the individual item in the jumplist and selecting "Remove from this list"?

Comment: I just went to try both but, after deleting the files (libs, sfi_hc.exe, sfi_hc.vhost.exe), the JumpList is gone.